# How can TFS build process be configured to execute tests on Test Agents through a Test Controller?

Tags: tfs, build-process, automated-tests

We have a Visual Studio test controller with 3 registered test agents in a specific test environment setup for our nightly automation runs.  I've seen ample documentation on having the build agents run the tests, but we need the test execution to go through the controller and run from the test agents instead.

My thought was to edit the build process template so it would trigger the execution of these remotely executed tests and then wait for the test run results, but I have no experience with build templates and I've been unable to find any examples showing how I might accomplish this.  And this is of course assuming that editing the build process is the best/correct solution in the first place.

Can someone with experience with triggering remote execution of tests at the end of a build/deploy cycle point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you don'have to change anything to your template. Just make sure your build definition refers to the correct tests and testsettings file that are configured for remote execution.

**Step 1:**
Please open http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx and scroll down to the section "Add a test settings for remote execution or data collection to your solution". Follow this to create a test settings file for remote execution.

**Step 2:**
Edit your build definition: go to the Process page, under heading "2. Basic", open the Automated Tests dialog by clicking the "..."at the end. It the Automated Tests dialog, click "Add". Then browse for your test settings file (for remote execution, the one you just created) and confirm your choices.

Now save your build definition and queue your build. Automagically, your tests are now performed on the remote system, because your testsettings file tells your build system to do so.

Hope that is enough to start your remote tests to work.

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks for saving me from doing it the hard way!