# Can I get TFS to deploy and execute tests on a different server?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, nunit, integration-testing, build-automation

I'm looking to get TFS to build and deploy to our manual and auto TEST environments.
manual TEST - overnight updates
auto   TEST - continuous integration

Once deployed, I want TFS to deploy and run a set of web-integration tests (SpecFlow / Selenium / nUnit) on another server (acting pseudo client of the website).
I then want TFS to collate the results of these tests and report back.

What's the best approach to get this working?

Comment: why dont you look at teamcity?

Comment: I like teamcity - it's great and I use it at home. But the University where I work is wed on TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally change the build process template to do what you want. Adding steps to deploy could be one of these customozations. Have a look at the [Build Release Deploy build template](http://vsarbrdlite.codeplex.com/) from the Microsoft ALM Rangers which includes steps to publish the build to another machine.

You can also make use of WebDeploy and add a set of publish profiles to your solution. [Team Build will happily execute those steps during build, if told to do so](http://chriskadel.com/2013/03/20/using-tfs-to-build-and-deploy-during-the-build-process-with-ms-deploy/).

In TFS you can use a [Test Agent to then execute tests from a remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7331110/736079) and have the results added to the test results for your build.

Seeing that you'd like to use NUnit ad SpecFlow I suggest using TFS 2012 in combination with Visual Studio 2012, which have built-in support for executing 3rd party based tests. [You'll need to install the NUnit adapter and put the assemblies for it in source control so that Team Build will pick them up](http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build).