# Alter TFS Build in order to deploy before executing tests

Tags: testing, deployment, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

As I'm using Selenium/MSTest for UI tests, I got a problem: I need to deploy an ASP.NET site to a *staging server* just before the automated tests are executed during a TFS build (TFS 2012).

Although I thought I could do this configuration in the TFS Build process template (`DefaultTemplate.xaml`), I can't figure out how to change the order to execute a **Build->Deploy->Test** flow.

Note I've found some how-tos aiding in this goal when using TFS Lab Environment, but this isn't my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved the problem chaining builds.

For example, when I queue a production build, this is the sequence:

1. Build, deploy to staging without UI tests
2. Build, no deploy, staging UI tests only
3. Build, deploy to production without UI tests
4. Build, no deploy, production UI tests only

I got the solution from this blog post:

- http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/

Post's author posted the modified DefaultTemplate.xaml (build definition) in GitHub Gist:

- https://gist.github.com/jstangroome/1196590/

Credits for the whole blogger!

Answer (score 1):

Default Template Unit Testing is different from UI Testing. Default template is designed to run Build -> Unit Test -> Deploy.

You are now in Build -> unit Test -> Deploy -> UI Test.

For UI Testing, You need separate Test Agent and set up build agent in interactive process.

These links may help

- http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Configuring-a-TFS-2010-Team-Build-Server-to-Run-Coded-UI-Tests.aspx
- http://blogs.infosupport.com/testing-your-web-application-with-selenium-and-mtm-part-1/
- http://blogs.infosupport.com/testing-your-web-application-with-selenium-and-mtm-part-2/

Comment: I appreciate your info, but I feel you didn't read my question at all. I know that now I'm in another flow, that's clear, but I was asking *how to implement such flow*. In addition, I said that I was aware about the Lab Manager approach... But I just want to run the UI tests, you know. Thank you anyway for your effort.

Comment: In addition, will you elaborate on "You need a separate Test Agent"? About "interactive process", I don't think so because I'm using PhantomJS. The tests are being executed with no problem. It's about *when* are executed. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for misunderstood your question. I thought you are trying to run the Coded UI Test after the build.  More details about Test agent in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265192/how-can-tfs-build-process-be-configured-to-execute-tests-on-test-agents-through/7331110#7331110 . I never tried the PhantomJS. I guess in your case to run the unit tests after the build, you need  custom Build Templates.

Comment: Well I got the solution using some other approach. I'll post it in some hours!

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to have an intermediate msbuild project file that is specified in your build definition and from there, call the actual solution file.

You can then do whatever is required pre- or post- build to ensure that the environment is up and running prior to TFS executing the tests. We do things like compile and deploy databases prior to TFS running our integration tests.

This is one solution that avoids having to manipulate the build template.